# Use capture group variable entered on command line in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

My goal is to pass a capture group variable (i.e. $1) that was entered on the command line to my Perl script.

To give you some background, I've created a script that takes a directory path, a pattern to search for and a replacement pattern. The script opens the directory, checks each file name to see if it matches the pattern and, if yes, changes the file name to be the replacement pattern.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
my ($directory, $pattern, $replacement) = @ARGV;

opendir DIR, $directory or die $!;

foreach my $old (readdir DIR){
    my $new = s/$pattern/$replacement/ if(/$pattern/);      
    rename "$directory$old" => "$directory$new";
}

close DIR;
```

Imagine that that script is called as:

```
script.pl "/tmp/" ".*(\d+).*" "$1"
```

The idea is that all the files will be renamed to be just the numbers found in the file name. The problem is that $1 is getting mangled. If it's passed using double quotes it's interpolated at assignment and becomes nothing. If it's passed using single quotes, then it's treated as a literal and all the files will be called "$1". How can I get the files to be renamed to just the numbers found in their names?

Comment: You can use the `rename` utility written by Larry Wall that does exactly what you describe.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I think you mean `prename`

Comment: Only `rename`, but `man rename` and `man prename` return the same manual page (where the utility is called "rename").

Comment: didn't know that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_copy );

my $subbed = gsub_copy($string, $pattern, $replacement);
```